# Meaning of building a dll as export library

Tags: dll

What is the meaning of building a dll as export library ? I just googled it.I found its a dynamic link library.Can anyone please explain what actually dll is ? and why do we need to add these statement in the .dll file

```
     extern  "c" _declspec(dllexport)
```

I studied the static and shared libraries but Im not sure why do we go for dll files.I learnt .dll is used for the run time. But can you help me and give me more information.Thank you in advance

Comment: Google is your friend. These are pretty basic concepts in programming, and there are plenty of websites that explain this. The tags you slapped on have nothing to do with the object of your question.

Comment: It does, because I downvoted. I think your question is not really useful; as I said, there are many websites out there that explain this just as well as anyone could do here in an answer. If you could point to a particular explanation, in which there are some specifics which are unclear to you, someone could possibly help you, but I don't see the point in repeating existing explanations.

Comment: what programming language are you asking for?

Comment: i did not mean a specifc language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have been a bit harsh in my comments. I am not an authority on dlls, but I have a bit of working knowledge of them, so I will try to give a short explanation.

The difference between static and shared libraries should be easy to find in a web search, but basically the code in a static library gets included into the final executable, so after the linking stage, the actual library file is not needed anymore to run the program; on the other hand, code in a shared library doesn't get included in the main program - the two parts remain separate, so the shared library (called dll on windows) will be needed every time the program is run.

"Building a dll as export library" is a bit of a confusing term. I had not heard of it before, and during a short search could only find it on a cygwin page, which you might have read, considering your initial tags. A dll can export some or all of its functions and data. Exporting means that they are available for other programs and dlls to use. Which names get exported can be controlled in various ways. One of those is inserting `_declspec(dllexport)` in the declaration of the function. Another way is by using a definition file with an exports section.

When creating a dll, an *import* library can be created. This is a file that can then be used when building an executable that uses the dll, during the linking stage, to let it know which names are exported from the dll, so the program knows how to resolve references to those functions; in other words: how to import them. (This is not always necessary. Many linkers allow you to directly link against the dll itself, thereby removing the need for an import library.)

I realize it can be confusing, but try to find a tutorial and some small examples to see how it works, and play with it a bit.